# Mule 4 anypoint studio in Debug Mode - can I change the payload value or a variable value

Tags: debugging, mule, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

This may not really be a code question , but many times when running Mule in debug mode in Anypoint studio ( Mule 4.3 , Anypoint Studio 7.15.0 ) , is there a way where while in Debug mode I can update the payload ( change its values ) ?

Essentially without restarting studio if I could change values of paylaod / variables I would be able to test my code and its behaviour in different scenarios ...

Answer (score 2):

In the Mule Debugger view go to the Payload or variable node that you want to update. Right-click on it, then click on the "Update value..." menu entry. If you want to set the value to a string put it between quotes.

### Examples

- Right-click on Payload:
  [image: Payload node]
- Right-click on a variable:
  [image: variable node]
- Updating the value:
  [image: string]